# Can't hide and add category on frontend in Prestashop 1.5

Tags: admin, prestashop, categories, prestashop-1.5

I'm new in Prestashop and I ask you about little help.

My client uses Prestashop 1.5 and she deleted one category and add one new category. Unfortunately we don't see these changes in category block on homepage and other pages.

Can you please help me how can I make these changes in admin? I looked for a solution in the category settings and in modules settings, but without success. I deleted cache in Prestashop and also in browser.

Can you please help me?

Thank you very much in advance.

Kind regards,

Jan Pavelka

[picture of backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smlZP.png) /
[picture of frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YloX2.png)

Answer (score 0):

What is name of this category module? This is blockcategories or it is different module? If it is different module maybe it has configuration page where you must edit displayed content like in module blocktopmenu.

Answer (score 0):

Could:

- Clear the cache from admin panel ;
- Very often the themes and modules have a " cache " separate checks if there are options to delete it or you cache modules ;
- If it appears also , try to look as if phpmyadmi in ps_category and ps_category_lang tables is still present that category (replace " PS_ " with the code you're using ) .

Let me know

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the great advice.

Finally, it was very simple (and stupid from my part). I only had a lower level of access to backend - that was the problem. For these things I need admin access.

Jan